# LyX Jurabib Style References Not Possible

Tags: cross-referencing, lyx

I was able to write the bulk of my thesis on LyX and I thought it will end that way. With the whooshing sound of the deadline in my ears, I am desperately looking for your help.

I am trying to insert citations in `jurabib` style and as a matter of fact, after a plethora of errors and some intuitive tweaking at the moment I ended up with a `?` sign where the citation should have been.

Since, I am a newbie I won't be able to provide details. Instead, I will beg your help by sharing my files.

[This is my thesis](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8054767/Haydi3.lyx).

[This is my `.bib` file](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8054767/Upload.bib) that I got through Zotero, output format is `bibtex`.

Lastly, this all the installed packages filtered by the word "latex":

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/15925).  A question mark indicates either that you have failed to run `bibtex` or that the entry was missing from your database.

Comment: Without any example - the links are broken - it is hard to answer.